# Dataproc Serverless - how to set javax.net.ssl.trustStore property to fix java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless

Trying to use  `google-cloud-dataproc-serveless` with `spark.jars.repositories` option

```
gcloud beta dataproc batches submit pyspark sample.py --project=$GCP_PROJECT --region=$MY_REGION --properties \
spark.jars.repositories='https://my.repo.com:443/artifactory/my-maven-prod-group',\
spark.jars.packages='com.spark.mypackage:my-module-jar',spark.dataproc.driverEnv.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=.,\
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=. -Djavax.net.debug=true' \
--files=my-ca-bundle.crt
```

giving this exception

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException
```

Tried to set this property `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` using `spark.dataproc.driverEnv`/`spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`, but its not working.

Is it possible to fix this issue by setting the right config properties and values,
or
**Custom Image is the ONLY solution, with pre installed certificates**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a Java [trust store](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html) with your cert imported. Then submit the batch with

```
--files=my-trust-store.jks \
--properties spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./my-trust-store.jks',spark.executor.extraJavaOptions='-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=./my-trust-store.jks'
```